# B-Tree implementing toString method in Node Class that is giving this error: Cannot invoke forEach((<no type> c) -> {}) on the array type Node<E>[]]

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, tostring, b-tree

I have Implemented B-Tree, I have given toString to Implement method in Node class as it but its giving errot in this line `children.forEach(c ->builder.append(c.toString(depth + 1)));` I have tried various methods but not worked

[here is other B-Tree files and pdf where is given toString Methods and other Instruction check out these files](https://github.com/Asghar267/B-Tree_imp)

[toString code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPvK0.png)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Node<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    public int nodeLocation;
    public int index;
    private E[] keys = null;
    int keysSize = 0;
    public Node<E>[] children = null;

    public Node<E>[] elements;

    int childrenSize = 0;
    private Comparator<Node<E>> comparator = new Comparator<Node<E>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Node<E> arg0, Node<E> arg1) {
            return arg0.getKey(0).compareTo(arg1.getKey(0));
        }
    };

    protected Node<E> parent = null;

    Node(Node<E> parent, int maxKeySize, int maxChildrenSize) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.keys = (E[]) new Comparable[maxKeySize + 1];
        this.keysSize = 0;
        this.children = new Node[maxChildrenSize + 1];
        this.childrenSize = 0;

    }

    E getKey(int index) {
        return keys[index];
    }

    int indexOf(E value) {
        for (int i = 0; i < keysSize; i++) {
            if (keys[i].equals(value))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    void addKey(E value) {
        keys[keysSize++] = value;
        Arrays.sort(keys, 0, keysSize);
    }

    E removeKey(E value) {
        E removed = null;
        boolean found = false;
        if (keysSize == 0)
            return null;
        for (int i = 0; i < keysSize; i++) {
            if (keys[i].equals(value)) {
                found = true;
                removed = keys[i];
            } else if (found) {
                // shift the rest of the keys down
                keys[i - 1] = keys[i];
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            keysSize--;
            keys[keysSize] = null;
        }
        return removed;
    }

    E removeKey(int index) {
        if (index >= keysSize)
            return null;
        E value = keys[index];
        for (int i = index + 1; i < keysSize; i++) {
            // shift the rest of the keys down
            keys[i - 1] = keys[i];
        }
        keysSize--;
        keys[keysSize] = null;
        return value;
    }

    int numberOfKeys() {
        return keysSize;
    }

    Node<E> getChild(int index) {
        if (index >= childrenSize)
            return null;
        return children[index];
    }

    int indexOf(Node<E> child) {
        for (int i = 0; i < childrenSize; i++) {
            if (children[i].equals(child))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    boolean addChild(Node<E> child) {
        child.parent = this;
        children[childrenSize++] = child;
        Arrays.sort(children, 0, childrenSize, comparator);
        return true;
    }

    boolean removeChild(Node<E> child) {
        boolean found = false;
        if (childrenSize == 0)
            return found;
        for (int i = 0; i < childrenSize; i++) {
            if (children[i].equals(child)) {
                found = true;
            } else if (found) {
                // shift the rest of the keys down
                children[i - 1] = children[i];
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            childrenSize--;
            children[childrenSize] = null;
        }
        return found;
    }

    Node<E> removeChild(int index) {
        if (index >= childrenSize)
            return null;
        Node<E> value = children[index];
        children[index] = null;
        for (int i = index + 1; i < childrenSize; i++) {
            // shift the rest of the keys down
            children[i - 1] = children[i];
        }
        childrenSize--;
        children[childrenSize] = null;
        return value;
    }

    int numberOfChildren() {
        return childrenSize;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */

    public String toStringg() {
        return toString(0);
    }

    // // based on what toString() does, think about what ‘elements’ and ‘children’
    // can be
    private String toString(int depth) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String blankPrefix = new String(new char[depth]).replace("\0", "\t");
        List<String> printedElements = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Node<E> e : elements)
            printedElements.add(e.toString());
        String eString = String.join(" :: ", printedElements);
        builder.append(blankPrefix).append(eString).append("\n");
        children.forEach(c -> builder.append(c.toString(depth + 1))); // this line is giving error
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

I Have Gievn pdf File where is gievn insructions and code implement I have tried to change childern but not worked I am bound to not make changes in gievn toString method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in Java doesn't declare their own behavior (don't try to reproduce your experience from languages like JavaScript and TypeScript, where Arrays have methods).

Therefore, you can't invoke method `forEach()` on the `children` array (this method is accessible with implementations of `Iterable` interface, like Collections).

You can use an enhanced `for`-loop instead:

```
for (Node<E> node : children) {
    builder.append(node.toString(depth + 1));
}
```

Alternatively, if you declare the property `children` as a `List` you'll be able use `forEach()` with it:

```
public List<Node<E>> children;
```

Judging by your assignment requirements, that what you're expected to do.

That would require changing all the methods that make use of `children` because you can't dial with a `List` in the same way as with an array. I.e. you would need to use the behavior of the [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#method-summary) interface.

`children[i]` would turn to `children.get(i)`. And `children[i] = ...` would become `children.set(i, ...)`, or `children.add(...)`.

Comment: Thanks it works as hint, but I am bounded to not make changes you can check out pdf file where is given instructions https://github.com/Asghar267/B-Tree_imp/blob/main/BinaryTrees.pdf

Comment: @AsgharAbbasi  It's **not** possible to invoke any method on an array, apart from methods declared in the `java.lang.Object` class. In order to use `forEach()`, `children` should be a Collection, for instance a `List`, i.e. it can be declared as `public List<Node<E>> children`

Comment: @AsgharAbbasi Have a look at the very bottom of the first page, you'll find a recommendation to use `ArrayList`s instead of arrays.

Comment: I have tried But It didn't work public List<Node<E>> children; I am Stuck now I don't know what to do could you review the code here are all files please see and help me what I have to do https://github.com/Asghar267/B-Tree_imp

Comment: @AsgharAbbasi Have you seen the last two sentences the in the answer? You need to make changes in **all** the methods that make use of `children`. And I gave you a couple of advises how to do it.  If you have a specific problem, then point at a particular line of code which causes issue.

Comment: Thanks for helping finally Solved